# Word/phrase meaning "prepare ahead of time"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase meaning "to prepare ahead of time" that is shorter / more cohesive?

For example, if I'm working on a recipe, let's say it takes 30 minutes to prepare the ingredients and 20 minutes to cook. If someone says "go" and I don't do any preparation it will take 50 minutes prior to serving. If I have time ahead of time, I can prepare the ingredients and it will only take 20 minutes between when someone says "go" and it's ready to serve.

I'm interested in something similar for software: preparing some kind of computation or processing, to minimize latency, so if there's a software-specific jargon, that would help too. ("instruction prefetch" is a term used in microprocessor design, but it doesn't apply to application software.)

Comment: That's pretty much what *prepare* means.

Comment: Get ready, warm up...

Comment: *prepare* is ambiguous, it can mean to be in a state of readiness but not actually do anything, it doesn't mean to complete portions of a task ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is for software, consider **preprogram** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preprogram)

> *verb* 1. Program (a computer or other electronic device) in advance
>
> *"a preprogrammed function key"*
>   *"The instrument we provide is preprogrammed for immediate operation."*
>
> 1.1 Program (something) into a computer or other electronic device before use
>
> *"preprogrammed messages"*
>   *"All it needed was to have preprogrammed responses for those 40,000 everyday utterances."*

Similarly, **preset** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preset)